# Trouble configuring Apache Tomcat Server on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am having trouble configuring my Tomcat on Eclipse. I followed the steps to set up a local Apache Tomcat Server on my Mac, and I also set up an SSL on the Tomcat Server successfully. However, after following instructions in setting up my Apache Tomcat server in eclipse, I keep getting errors saying the following:

HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource is not available.

If it makes any difference, I removed the web project I was trying to make when creating my server. It also doesn't work when I try to boot it up on Terminal--I end up with the same message. Any help would be appreciated trying to decipher this error message! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "ROOT" folder of your tomcat seems to be empty. Either you did not add an application to your Tomact config ("Server" view) or you have to check your "Server location" settings, double click on your servers name in the same view.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but how would you check your server location settings?

Comment: In Eclipse main menu click 'window' -> 'view' -> 'other' and select 'server'. There double click on the servers name.